# Binding same function to different elements in jquery

Tags: jquery

The following code won't work if i replace id with variable. I tried different combination but didn't work. I am using on form elements. Please let me know if anyone knows how to get this work. Thanks.

This works:

```
$('#Button1, #Button2').click(function() {
// 
});
```

Here is my sample code that doesn't work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>                    <script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
   var Btn1 = $("#buy");
       var Btn2 = $("#preview");        
   $(Btn1, Btn2).click(function(){ console.log("hey");})        
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
      <input type="button" value="Preview" id="preview" />
      <input type="button" value="Buy" id="buy" />
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Side note: you should indent your code properly if you don't want to get lost in a labyrinth of jQuery chained methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concat jQuery elements and assign click function on both.

```
Btn1.add(Btn2).click(function(){ 
    console.log("hey");
});
```

Better solution would be giving some class to buttons then assigning click on them:

```
$('.myButton').click(function() { 
    console.log("hey");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also separate the function from the event binding. This can a powerful technique for more advance uses.

```
var my_func = function(){ console.log("hey");}

$("#buy").click(my_func);
$("#preview").click(my_func);
```

Answer (score 1):

More easy solution :)

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function(){
   console.log("hey");
});
```

Or simply give common style class to all buttons

```
 <input type="button" class=".buttonClass" value="Preview" id="preview" />
 <input type="button" class=".buttonClass" value="Buy" id="buy" />
```

below is the required javascript.

```
  $(".buttonClass").click(function(){
           console.log("hey");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are putting your jquery elements in separate variables and are using these in your function call. The comma will not act as expected in your solution.
You can use the selector like this $('#buy, #preview'). Your JS code would then look like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#buy, #preview').click(function(){ console.log("hey");})        
    });
```